# The initialization function is called twice in a `lazy_static` block

Tags: rust, singleton, lazy-static

I have a big project Where I use `lazy_static` to create a `singleton`. I think there is a bug in `lazy_static` crate (which appears in big projects only) or I am doing something wrong because the initialization function which must be called once to create the singleton is called twice.

The structure of the project is as follows

---

```
Foo
|__foo-core
|  |__src
|  |  |__lib.rs
|  |__Cargo.toml
|
|__foo-high
|  |__src
|  |  |__lib.rs
|  |__Cargo.toml
|
|__src
|  |__lib.rs
|__Cargo.toml
```

---

Foo/foo-core/src/lib.rs

```
pub mod my_file {
    pub struct MyFile {
        file: std::fs::File,
    }

    impl MyFile {
        pub fn open(
            path: &'static str,
        ) -> Result<MyFile, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
            let file_ = std::fs::File::create(path)?;
            Ok(MyFile { file: file_ })
        }
    }
}
```

Foo/foo-high/src/lib.rs

```
mod high {
    mod high_child {
        #[cfg(test)]
        mod high_child_unit_tests {
            use crate::high::my_file::*;

            #[test]
            fn some_fun_test_runner() {
                MyFile::get();
                auto_fun();
                MyFile::get();
            }

            fn auto_fun() {
                // super::super::layer ::some_fun();
                foo::high::some_fun();
            }
        }
    }

    pub mod layer {
        use crate::high::my_file::*;

        pub fn some_fun() {
            MyFile::get();
        }
    }

    mod my_file {
        pub use foo_core::my_file as core_my_file;
        use std::sync::{Mutex, MutexGuard};
        lazy_static::lazy_static! {static ref INSTANCE: Mutex<core_my_file::MyFile> = init_fun();}

        fn init_fun() -> Mutex<core_my_file::MyFile> {
            println!("INIT");
            let location = "location.txt";
            Mutex::new(core_my_file::MyFile::open(location).expect("\nSome Error has occurred."))
        }

        pub struct MyFile {}

        impl MyFile {
            pub fn get() -> MutexGuard<'static, core_my_file::MyFile> {
                println!("GET");
                INSTANCE.lock().expect("The mutex has been poisoned")
            }
        }
    }
}

pub mod layer {
    pub use crate::high::layer::*;
}
```

Foo/foo-core/Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "foo-core"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
```

Foo/foo-high/Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "foo-high"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
foo-core = { version = "0.1.0", path = "../foo-core" }
lazy_static = "1.4.0"

[dev-dependencies]
foo = { version = "0.1.0", path = "../" }
```

Foo/Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
foo-high = { version = "0.1.0", path = "foo-high" }

[workspace]
members = ["foo-high", "foo-core"]
```

When I ran the `some_fun_test_runner` test with `-- --no-capture`, I see 3 `GET`s and 2 `INIT`s while `INIT` must print only once.
When I changed the architecture, the function was called once but I need this architecture.
And when I changed `foo::high::some_fun();` (in auto_fun) to `super::super::layer::some_fun();`, the function was called once too.
I can't understand this behavior. I used `once_cell` too but I have got the same results

Comment: There's a lot of extra noise in this question: foo-core/, the file specific stuff, and all the modules are unnecessary. [Minimal sample here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2ecd74d879727308ce9c89eab670c891). The cyclic dev-dependency seems important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an indirectly cyclic dependency with `foo-high` -> `foo` workspace -> `foo-high` again. Rust and Cargo weren't designed with dependency cycles in mind; your architecture should avoid them. To be precise, your problem arises because both instances of `foo-high` have their own set of `static`s.

In the unit test, `super::super::layer::some_fun` means a fn in crate variant "A", whereas `foo::high::some_fun` means a fn in crate variant "B". The former works fine in your context, whereas the latter uncovers the issue with separate `static`s. Such duplication happens here, but also when different crate versions are pulled in somewhere down the dependency graph.

I'm not sure about the motivation behind your crate architecture, but one potential solution is to remove the dev-dependency on `foo`. Then, to fake your desired module structure, you may have the following: You add at the root of `foo-high`

```rust
mod foo {
    mod high {
        pub use crate::*;
    }
    pub use foo_core as core;
}
```

---

What's more, it's uncommon for a unit test to reference items by their global path. It's best to keep things local. Otherwise, it may be preferable to write an integration test instead.

Comment: It's definitely `foo-high` being "de-duplicated". One odd thing though, `cargo tree` doesn't actually show that. Separating the "root" crate into it's own crate, then the issue of course persists. However, then `cargo tree` actually shows it's being de-duplicated. Just an odd observation I had.

Comment: does this mean if the initialization function is called from n different crates in the same program I will have n instances?